# How do Activites follow eachother on Android studio?

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to learn some android Dev too and I am saving my data to sql and I am trying to save data on the signup but when data is successful it loads a different activity instead of main Activity this is my code. I want my method `onSignupSuccess` to open MainActivity.class I am not getting any Errors It instead opens

```
DisplayLogoActivity"
```

Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".activities.DisplayLogoActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActiviy"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SignupActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark" />
```

My onSignupSuccess Method

```
  public void onSignupSuccess(int userId) {
        signUpBT.setEnabled(true);

        Session session = new Session(getBaseContext());
        session.setuserId(userId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
        finish();
    }
```

My MainActivity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Session session = new Session(getBaseContext());
        if (session.getuserId() == 0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
```

My Session

```
public class Session {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public Session(Context cntx) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
    }

    public void setuserId(int userId) {
        prefs.edit().putInt("userId", userId).commit();
    }

    public int getuserId() {

        return prefs.getInt("userId", 0);
    }

    public void logout() {
        prefs.edit().remove("userId").commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your Session static, global, available for the whole application?

Comment: Added it , please help me.

Comment: Are you starting your LoginActivity only on your MainActivity, as you wrote here or are you starting it on your ShowLogoActivity aswell?

Comment: MainActivity will not be recreated from the startActivity, if you expecting the else to be executed afterwards. From your question: You probably starting the other Activity behind Login, and when the login ends it come backs to the hidden one.

Comment: So let's say I am starting display logo, which after it is done it opens LoginActivity, LoginActiviy has signup and Create which it opens well, now on Signup is where I get the problem it takes me back to DisplayLogo instead of the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a complete picture,

if you have activities A (DisplayLogoActivity), B (LoginActivity), C (MainActivity)

And if you call finish() method on B activity, just that activity will disappear from history stack, and last activity that has been opened before activity with finish() call, will be opened.

So in your case,

you have three possibilities to solve this problem (two from @Massita), and another one is to call finish() method also when you start B activity from A, something like this flow:

1. Open DisplayLogoActivity
2. Start activity LoginActivity from DisplayLogoActivity and call FINISH()
3. On LoginActivity check is OK data for that user if yes, then start activity MainActivity and call FINISH()

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the LoginActivity on your DisplayLogoActivity, when you finish the LoginActivity, the android will pop the "activity stack", so, the activity that will be shown is the DisplayLogoActivity.

To solve this, you can start your LoginActivity waiting for a result, with the [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) and, when you receive the result, if it's a OK, you start the MainActivity, or do whatever you want to do if the user is not logged in.

Another approach is to start your MainActivity on the DisplayLogoActivity instead of the Login. And use this code you have, to check if the user is logged in when the MainActivity is created, to start(or not) the LoginActivity.